# Primefaces commandButton not work inside a Carousel

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 4.0 and jsf 2.0.

I'm trying to call a method of my managed bean, in a Primefaces commandbutton inside a Carousel, but it does not work. It Looks like that the button can't call the method. 
Nothing happens...

So, i've looked for, but i can't found anything that help-me to solve this problem.

bellow my code:

Page.xhtml

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>

<h:form id="form">
<p:carousel id="tabsCarousel" numVisible="1" itemStyle="height:500px;width:800px;" effect="easeInStrong">  
    <p:tab title="Godfather Part I">  

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">   
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/godfather/godfather1.jpg" />  
            <h:outputText  value="Some text" />  
                <p:commandButton value="ok" action="#{bean.test}"  />
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:tab>
</p:carousel> 
</h:form> 
</h:body>
</html>
```

And the method of managed bean

```
    public void test(){
         System.out.print("Here!");
    }
```

OBS: The scope of may bean is ViewScoped.

PLEASE!

Thanks !!!!!

Comment: Can you try adding `process="@this"` to the button?

Comment: Yes, i put this on commandbutton, but did not work .. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to be related with [this reported issue](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=%204847), even it's supposed to be marked as fixed for 3.5, I tested it with 3.5 and 4 (Community versions) and seems to be still there. There's also [another report](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=%203903) for the problem, given `p:tab` components instead of `p:column`, like in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but in showcase, the carousel is used with tabs too, look http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/carouselTabs.jsf. So i would to use a panelGrid inside of tab in carousel and calls the method..

Comment: Ok, good catch. I totally changed my answer, I looked for more info and it seems like it's related with a known bug. I don't know if they have fixed for elite releases.

Comment: Really, unfortunately ... but, thanks for your reply ! So, i tried use the accordion to replace this, with tabs, and this work fine.. the problem is the carousel ...